# Android: the owner of files under /mnt/sdcard

Tags: android, sd-card

I found that the owner:group of the files under /mnt/sdcard is always system:sdcard_rw. Even when I su to root and create a file, the owner is still system:sdcard_rw.

Is there anything special about files under /mnt/sdcard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filesystem on sdcard is probably vfat (fat32) which does not store information of user and group. Owner and group of the mount point are used.

The user and group are defined by the mount options. Here is sample mount output for my AVD:

> /dev/block/vold/179:0 /mnt/sdcard **vfat**
>   rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,**uid=1000,gid=1015**,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso885

Comment: thanks! actually, i found that the file system is tmpfs.

Comment: The file system cannot be tmpfs. tmpfs is a RAM-only file system, not applicable to physical devices like SD cards.

Comment: @Todd, I updated answer with sample mount output which shows it would be vfat, maybe you meant /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure mount point which is mounted as tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

SD cards are typically formatted as FAT32, which doesn't support setting access rights to files.